# Does the optimistic UI only work with watch Query?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Does the optimistic UI only work with watchQuery and not with subscription ? We are using subscription over websocket extensively and can't manage to make the optimistic UI work, although it seems to work fine with watchQuery.

So my question is simple, I just need confirmation that the optimistic ui should work with a subscribe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watchQuery is used to subscribe to updates to your cache (Apollo often refers to this as a 'store'), which is not the same as your server. See this note from Apollo's [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client.html#ApolloClient.watchQuery):

> This watches the cache store of the query according to the options specified and returns an ObservableQuery. We can subscribe to this ObservableQuery and receive updated results through a GraphQL observer when the cache store changes. Note that this method is not an implementation of GraphQL subscriptions. Rather, it uses Apollo's store in order to reactively deliver updates to your query results.

A full server based implementation is called GraphQL Subscriptions. Subscription updates are something the client receives at an arbitrary time. When they come, they come. Since a prediction cannot be made, there is no use case for optimistic UI in subscriptions. Thus why, they are not supported. The only use case I can think of is if the client is subscribing to it's own changes. In that case, you could use the optimisticResponse and update options off of the [Mutation component](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#mutation) that you are doing the update with.